# Resize java script snippet

Tags: javascript

### Need to resize this, pls support

---

begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

```html
<script type ="text/javascript">
amzn_assoc_placement = "adunit0";
amzn_assoc_search_bar = "true";
amzn_assoc_tracking_id = "buysell0b-20";
amzn_assoc_ad_mode = "manual";
amzn_assoc_ad_type = "smart";
amzn_assoc_marketplace = "amazon";
amzn_assoc_region = "US";
amzn_assoc_title = "My Amazon Picks";
amzn_assoc_debug = "false";
amzn_assoc_ead = "0";
amzn_assoc_linkid = "1741f4677bbde5cd7c47aa9bad758d44";
amzn_assoc_asins = "B003D4MX1E,B006J3S9WI,B000GFYRK8,B0009F3PM6,B000F4DKCG,B006N3I9OC,B001E95KO2";
</script>
<script src="//z-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/onejs?MarketPlace=US"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding

```
amzn_assoc_isresponsive = 'true';
```

Which should allow the widget to automatically adapt [[Amazon Help Article]](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/promotion/mec/widgets)